# How to get type of this keyword in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, this, prototype

I'm manipulating the prototype of `Object` so that I can add some extension methods.
I've found out that `typeof` operator always returns `object` in case the operand is `this`:

```
Object.prototype.logType = function () { console.log(typeof this); }
"Hello".logType()
```

output of code above is `object` instead of `string`. I know that in JavaScript everything is  indeed an `object`, However I need to know the exact type of the value of `this`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Duplicate of [Messing with this in prototype's method](/q/20432009/4642212): simply put your code in [strict mode](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). This is also mentioned in [How does the “this” keyword work?](/q/3127429/4642212).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call a method on a primitive, JS automatically wraps that primitive in its associative object wrapper, so:

```
"Hello".logType()
```

becomes:

```
new String("Hello").logType()
```

hence, `this` inside of your logType function refers to the wrapped primitive value, giving you an object. You can call [`.valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) to grab the primitive value wrapped in the object:

```js
Object.prototype.logType = function () { console.log(typeof this.valueOf()); }

"Hello".logType(); // string
(1).logType(); // number
true.logType(); // boolean
1n.logType(); // bigint
Symbol().logType(); // symbol
(() => {}).logType(); // function
({}).logType(); // object
```

Or, you can use strict mode as suggested in the comments, as that keeps `this` as the original primitve:

```js
Object.prototype.logType = function () { "use strict"; console.log(typeof this); }

"Hello".logType(); // string
(1).logType(); // number
true.logType(); // boolean
1n.logType(); // bigint
Symbol().logType(); // symbol
(() => {}).logType(); // function
({}).logType(); // object
```

Comment: you could also use `this.constructor.name` - which will also work for your own `class`es (`.valueOf()` shows `object`)

Comment: This will incorrectly return `true` though if I use `(new class String {}).logType()` which is not a string. Better use `this.constructor === String`.

Comment: "return true" ... there is no true returned anywhere @CherryDT

Comment: @JaromandaX nice, yeah, that might be a better option if OP wants to get the constructor names instead of the data types

Comment: Yeah sorry, I extrapolated that with `=== 'String'` in my mind, since that's the only logical thing you can do with it in this case

Comment: `\`${typeof this.valueOf() === this.constructor.name.toLowerCase()?'#':''}${this.constructor.name}\`` - will output `#String` for actual Strings, and just `String` for class String ... or `XXX` for class XXX etc - if you want that level of granularity

Comment: This is probably beyond what anyone would ever encounter but... `new class String { valueOf () { return "abc" } }` << oops - I guess the closest you can get would be `${typeof this.valueOf() === this.constructor.name.toLowerCase() && this.constructor === globalThis[this.constructor.name]?'#':''}${this.constructor.name}`

Comment: @CherryDT hm yeah, you're right about that. Nice addition checking the global object for the constructor, wouldn't have thought of doing that myself

Comment: ...wait strict mode also changes this behavior... so all this is useless and we should just enable strict mode in the place where the prototype function is defined

Answer (score 4):

When passed as `this` **outside of strict mode**, you have the very rare case that you encounter a primitive in their wrapped object form ("boxed"), as instance of `String`:

[image]

You can therefore check if your method was called on a string using `this instanceof String` instead of `typeof this === 'string'`. If you want to differentiate between strings and objects that inherit from `String`, you could use `this.constructor === String` instead.

To get a "regular" string back (or number for `Number`, or boolean from `Boolean`, etc.), you can call `this.valueOf()`

(This means you could also write `typeof this.valueOf()` - but note that this may be misleading because any object could return, say, a string from its `valueOf` method without actually having been a string originally.)

Note: You cannot differentiate between `'abc'.yourMethod()` and `new String('abc').yourMethod()` this way because you get an instance of `String` either way.

<sub>(Also interesting: Seems like for newer types like `BigInt` or `Symbol` you cannot manually create such a wrapper instance, `new BigInt(1n)` will fail. But `(function () { return this }).call(1n)` would achieve the same, although I have no idea why anybody would want that...)</sub>

---

All that said: The *easiest* way to get the exact behavior you want (`this` being the actual string) is by defining your function in a context that is in **strict mode**:

```js
(function {
  'use strict'
  Object.prototype.logType = function () { console.log(typeof this); }
})()
```

Now it will work as intended.